# XAMPP not working

Tags: php, xampp

I am new to ubuntu. I have **installed XAMPP** and i have been using it for 2 months without any problem. I was able to access XAMPP by typing '*localhost*' on the browser. 3 days back i have **installed DRUPAL** from **ubuntu software center** and now if i try to start XAMPP using
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
the message i get is this,

Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: Another web server daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP for Linux started.

and if i try to access localhost, I am getting a page saying,

It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

From this message i understood that the localhost have been changed to /var/www from /opt/lamp. So i tried to uninstall DRUPAL from software center, but still the problem remains. I need XAMPP back. Could anyone please suggest how can i solve this?

Comment: Please do not use the lamp tag for xamp :) and XAMP -ALWAYS- installs in /opt. This is hard codes. Install LAMP if you want flexibility :)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Please specify which Ubuntu version are you running and which packages have you installed to get that software.

Answer (score 0):

You have installed XAMPP --> how !?

by installing drupal, the package manager installed all required dependencies for it, this should include mysql, apache, php, etc. 
now the system has 2 webservers, mysql's, the ones installed by you and the seconds installed by package manager, which are started by default on system launch

the default root-path for new web server is /var/www/

what I suggest you, is to remove your old xampp and start using the default web server, which is also an apache

How to remove the old one !? --> that depends on how you installed it

if you need specific version of apache (lamp, xampp, etc.), you can start here --> https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/apache2

to continue using your previous instalation, remove the new apache, or stop it using (after each reboot):

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service mysql stop
```

then start your old xampp

of course anything can be configured in more appropriate way, but this is another topic

ps. a suggestion, install core apps form package manager, and things like drupal or wordpress from sources (you should not compile them)